# Fetching Data From xlsx sheet, not showing last three rows in jtable

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to fetching data from excel sheet(.xlsx) file. when I use to print fetched data using

System.out.println(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(c).getStringCellValue()); I see the all the rows from excel sheet is fetched. But when I add this data in jtable it misses last three rows and shows following error:

***Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.getCell(int)" because the return value of "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.getRow(int)" is null***

```
enter code here


     JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser("D:");
    
        int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

        FileName = selectedFile.getName();
        String FilePath = selectedFile.getPath();
        System.out.println(FileName);
        System.out.println(FilePath);
      
        File excelfile = new File(FileName);
        
       try{ 
       
       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
         
       XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
       XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
       int totalrows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
       
                
    
       for (int i = 0; i <=totalrows; )
       {
    
        dmodel.addRow(new Object[]{"" });
     
       System.out.println(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());   // this line work
       String name = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();  
       jTable1.setValueAt(name , i, 0);    // this line does not work        
        
       i++ ;
      
       
       
      } 
       
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All rows are fetched Successfully" );
       
       
       
   }catch(Exception fx)
          {
          System.out.println(fx.getMessage()); 
         // System.out.println(fx.getCause());
          
          }
```

Comment: However if i add three empty rows in  excel sheet  in the bottom of the sheet then it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is thrown at the line you indicated? It seems strange to me that you recive an ApachePoi-related error which is thrown at a line that has nothing to do with ApachePoi but only refears to the use of a JTable (mabye you should post the full error).

Answer (score 1):

```
   System.out.println(sheet.getRow(r).getCell(c).getStringCellValue());   // this line work
   String name = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(c).getStringCellValue();  
   jTable1.setValueAt(name , i, 0);    // this line does not work
```

Don't know if this will solve your problem, but the above code is not how you use System.out.println(...) to debug your logic.

To verify the data you use:

```
   //System.out.println(sheet.getRow(r).getCell(c).getStringCellValue());   // this line work
   String name = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(c).getStringCellValue();  
   System.out.println( name );
   jTable1.setValueAt(name , i, 0);    // this line does not work
```

Don't attempt to read the data twice. By assigning the data to a variable you are debugging the data in the variable. Don't repeat the nested methods multiple times.

Maybe the class expects you to only read the data once, so the second read gives the null value. The simple change above will prevent this.

Comment: I am using only these line    String name = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(c).getStringCellValue();           jTable1.setValueAt(name , i, 0);

Comment: this line only used to verify where is the issue is System.out.println(sheet.getRow(r).getCell(c).getStringCellValue());     and this fetches all the rows correctly.

Comment: *this line only used to verify where is the issue is* - Do you not understand what I suggested? Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Step 1 is to use the two lines of code I provided, in the order I provide, and comment out the code related to the table. It should work and simply display the values. Then you simply add back in the table logic. Adding a value to the table will have nothing to do with the spreadsheet, it is just taking data from a variable. If you get an error it will be an  error unrelated to the spreadsheet.